# Python: How to develop a between_time similar method when on pandas 0.9.0?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.5

I am stick to pandas 0.9.0 as I'm working under python 2.5, hence I have no [between_time](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) method available.

I have a DataFrame of dates and would like to filter all the dates that are between certain hours, e.g. between `08:00` and `09:00` for all the dates within the DataFrame `df`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

dates = pd.date_range(start="08/01/2009",end="08/01/2012",freq="10min")
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(dates), 1)*1500, index=dates, columns=['Power'])
```

How can I develop a method that provides same functionality as `between_time` method?

N.B.: The original problem I am trying to accomplish is under [Python: Filter DataFrame in Pandas by hour, day and month grouped by year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117702/python-filter-dataframe-in-pandas-by-hour-day-and-month-grouped-by-year)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

try to use:

```
df.loc[df.index.indexer_between_time('08:00','09:50')]
```

**OLD answer:**

I'm not sure that it'll work on Pandas 0.9.0, but it's worth to try it:

```
df[(df.index.hour >= 8) & (df.index.hour <= 9)]
```

PS please be aware - it's not the same as `between_time` as it checks only hours and `between_time` is able to check **time** like `df.between_time('08:01:15','09:13:28')`

**Hint**: download a source code for a newer version of Pandas and take a look at the definition of `indexer_between_time()` function in   `pandas/tseries/index.py` - you can clone it for your needs

---

**UPDATE:** starting from Pandas 0.20.1 [the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-ix).

Comment: Seems to work for hours at least. However this way I get from 08:00 till 09:50. And if I try df[(df.index.hour >= 8) & (df.index.hour < 9)] I get from 08:00 till 08:50, and 09:00 is excluded.

Comment: Seems [pandas 0.10.0](https://pypi.python.org/packages/b2/35/551eae108f71e9e80a8778e4ae6d36207916ec841e497fff5b8affa63857/pandas-0.10.0.zip#md5=7a9e05448f86ce3e8b73370d87765926) has already between_time implemented.

Comment: Try this `df.ix[df.index.indexer_between_time('08:00','09:50')]` in Pandas 0.9.0?

Comment: `pd.tseries.indexer_between_time()` is not available in `pandas 0.9.0`. I am digging into `pandas 0.10.0`but I find this can be kind of messy to implement as there are many new libraries that are used and not defined in `pandas 0.9.0`

Comment: Great @MaxU ! This new solution would be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a NumPy-based way of doing it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

dates = pd.date_range(start="08/01/2009",end="08/01/2012",freq="10min")
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(dates), 1)*1500, index=dates, columns=['Power'])

epoch = np.datetime64('1970-01-01')
start = np.datetime64('1970-01-01 08:00:00')
end = np.datetime64('1970-01-01 09:00:00')

# convert the dates to a NumPy datetime64 array
date_array = df.index.asi8.astype('<M8[ns]') 

# replace the year/month/day with 1970-01-01
truncated = (date_array - date_array.astype('M8[D]')) + epoch

# compare the hour/minute/seconds etc with `start` and `end`
mask = (start <= truncated) & (truncated <=end)

print(df[mask])
```

yields

```
                           Power
2009-08-01 08:00:00  1007.289466
2009-08-01 08:10:00   770.732422
2009-08-01 08:20:00   617.388909
2009-08-01 08:30:00  1348.384210
...
2012-07-31 08:30:00   999.133350
2012-07-31 08:40:00  1451.500408
2012-07-31 08:50:00  1161.003167
2012-07-31 09:00:00   670.545371
```

Comment: Not sure if this may be because I am running Pythn 2.5, but I get below Error trying your solution: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<module1>", line 8, in <module>
TypeError: Cannot parse "1970-01-01" as unit 'ns' using casting rule 'same_kind'

Comment: Ah, I forgot you would need [NumPy version 1.7 or greater](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.datetime.html) to use this code.

Comment: That's strange @unutbu, as I have Numpy version 1.7.1

Comment: I've changed the code to use `epoch = np.datetime64('1970-01-01')` instead of `epoch = np.array(['1970-01-01'], dtype='<M8[ns]')`.  This should be [valid in NumPy 1.7](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.datetime.html#string-parsing).

Comment: Now I get following Error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: Hm. I've clearly forgotten pandas 0.9 syntax. Perhaps try `df[mask]` or `df.ix[mask]`.